# laravel model morph to itself and other models

Tags: php, laravel

i'm in misunderstanding concept of laravel elequent models
i have an  model called Article that has a table with columns

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('feature_image')->nullable();
        $table->text('intro')->nullable();
        $table->text('content')->nullable();
        $table->string('seo_title')->nullable();
        $table->string('seo_meta')->nullable();
        $table->string('seo_keywords')->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('state')->default(0)->index();
        $table->string('lang')->default('fa')->index();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
```

also a product model with name products with some columns
i want to have related articles and products for each article and product model
i mean i want to save related articles for an article when i'm creating a new article record , same for products
any hint would help.

what about if i just want to have related articles of an article ?

Comment: here is a hint. read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent and do tutorials https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Comment: @N69S tnx , but i'm confused about self many to many or polymorphic relationship of models in laravel

Comment: again, read the documentation about those relations and do the tutorial about those kind of relations

Comment: @N69S no documentation around self many to many relationship, like a post has many posts and reverse

Comment: here you go https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @N69S tnx for your reply , but i think there is misunderstanding concept between us , what you refer to is talking about morphing a model named tags to other models named post and video , i want to morph a model to itself and other models , for example a post has many posts related on and products related , other model (product in my example  ) is not my problem , my problem is about self post model that i want to save a post as a new record and an array of posts that are related to that new posts

Comment: so a simple many to many relation with a pivot table to link between a post and other posts.

Comment: tnx again @N69S , i create a table with two columns , article_id and related_id and named it article_article table , and fill it with two records 1 , 2 and 2 , 1 . in my article model declare a function that returns <code>  $this->hasMany('App\Article','article_article','article_id','related_id'); </code>   it returns an empty array

Comment: that's seems a correct approach, happy to help :)

Comment: @N69S thank you , but i have an empty array ;))

Comment: depends on how you declare the relations

Comment: If you want articles with children (and children have a 'master' or 'parent') I can share my code for this. In the view you implement a recursive loop and done. As it is 40 lines of code I need to post it as an answer.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey i would be very greatfull

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is as follows (the Article model). In the migrations I've added a column

```
$table->integer('master')->unsigned()->after('user_id')->default(0)->index()
                  ->comment('Articles can be linked to an other article');
```

The model and relationships:

```
 /**
     * An article can belong to another article
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo Article
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'master', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * An article can have many linked articles
     *
     * @return HasMany Article
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'master', 'id');
    }
```

In the controller, basically:

```
$articles = Article::where('master', '0')->with('children')->get();
```

Finally the view:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
     @include('articles.article_item_well', ['recursive' => true])
@endforeach
```

On the bottom of 'articles.article_item_well' add this:

```
@if ($recursive && count($article->children) > 0)
    <div class="card-body">
        @foreach($article->children as $article)
            @include('articles.article_item_well')
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Where the blade snippet 'articles.article_item_well' prints out each article, no matter how deeply nested.

There is only one catch with this system that is (as far as I know) unresolvable. And that's pagination. There is no way to paginate children and children of children to 15 a page in total. It will take 15 'master' articles (with value '0) and has no awareness of how many articles are nested inside. I tried to solve this, looked everywhere but to no avail. In my situation it didn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you , but actually its not the right solution, in your answer we are relating a model to itself one-to-one and retrieving them in a recursive loop, what actually im looking for is a many to many pivot table for one model , i did this but got no chance on it . im thinking about creating a field in my article table to save an array of article ids that related to a specific article